# Vertex bevel going the wrong way

Tags: vertices, bevel

i was following a tutorial on making a soccer field. When i got to the beveling the vertex, it's going the opposite way. It's making the inner curve instead of the outer curve.

[image]

Comment: What esxactly are you trying to bevel? You don't seem to have anything in view selected in your image. It might help if we could see your Blend file. You can share it via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there to copy the link to it and then edit your question and paste the link into it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because your *Shape* option has a small value. From the [docs](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/edge/bevel.html#options):

> This is a number between 0 and 1 that controls the shape of the profile (side view of a beveled edge). The default value, 0.5, gives a circular arc (if the faces meet at right angles). Values less than that give a flatter profile, with 0.25 being exactly flat, and values less than that giving a concave bevel. Values more than 0.5 give a more convex profile.

[image]